# Use Microsoft Graph REST API with a back-end user in Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have struggles to find a proper way to authenticate a full priviledged user in web api for Microsoft Graph REST API. The intention is to have a user authentication on my Web API and then execute file modifications with a different, application used only user to modify files in OneDrive.

Are there any resources and hints for this use case? I can only find examples where the actual end-user is redirected to authenticate with the Microsoft login and give permission.

Using [app only](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only) seems to work but I'm not sure how to include it in the Web API

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your scenario? The web api app is designed for users with microsoft accounts , organization uses(Azure AD users) ,or just for yourself ?

Comment: The intended use is for Office365 Accounts to access files through OneDrive. I just provided an answer to my own question which uses the `Microsoft Graph .NET Client` and acquires an Access Token for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("AuthURI");
        var clientCred = new ClientCredential("ClientID","ClientSecret");

        AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/...", clientCred);
        accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

        var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
       {
           requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }));

        var drives = await graphserviceClient.Drives.Request().GetAsync();
```